# __construct not creating a new array

Tags: php, arrays, constructor

I'm new to PHP and OOP, I'm trying to create a new array $service with the constructor inside the SummationService, but it never gets created so the sum function is only receiving (0, 0) and throws bunch of errors. If i declare the array with the values inside the function, it works properly. The result should be -1.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$service = new SummationService([-1, 0, 2, 7, -15]);
echo $service->sum(0, 0);

class SummationService {
    public $array;

    function __construct(){
        $this->array = array();
    }

    function sum($a, $b): int {
        return array_sum(array_slice($array, $a, $b - $a + 1));
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The errors are as follows:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: array in D:\xampproot\htdocs\index.php on line 16

Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in D:\xampproot\htdocs\index.php on line 16

Warning: array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in D:\xampproot\htdocs\index.php on line 16

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of SummationService::sum() must be of the type int, null returned in D:\xampproot\htdocs\index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampproot\htdocs\index.php(6): SummationService->sum(0, 0) #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampproot\htdocs\index.php on line 16
```

---

Edit:

Line 16 is `return array_sum(array_slice($array, $a, $b - $a + 1));`

Comment: Which is line 35? Your code doesn't go that high.

Comment: Please do tell us which line is LINE 35 of the 21 lines of code you show us

Comment: Great minds @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ditto. Am thinking they probably can't use the word `array` as it might be reserved but couldn't say for sure; thoughts?

Comment: This line calls the constructor `$service = new SummationService([-1, 0, 2, 7, -15]);` You are poassing a parameter !!! But the constructor does not have a parameter in its parameter list ??? So `$this->array` is an EMPTY ARRAY

Comment: You meant `$this->array` and not `$array` in `return array_sum(array_slice($array, $a, $b - $a + 1));`

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry, the line 35 is `return array_sum(array_slice($array, $a, $b - $a + 1));`

Comment: Ok thanks @IntenseFlegde - I added that in the question. Food for thought: In the future, could you add any errors also? That way, everyone is on the same page ;-) cheers.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I changed the errors as well, now it shows properly as line 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating the class with a parameter, but your `__construct()` does not have a parameter.

Also you are addressing the class property `$array` incorrectly in the `sum` method.

```
class SummationService {
    public $array;

    function __construct($ar){
        $this->array = $ar;
    }

    function sum($a, $b): int {

        return array_sum(array_slice($this->array, $a, $b - $a + 1));
            // addressing corrected  ^^^^^^^
    }
}


$service = new SummationService([-1, 0, 2, 7, -15]);
echo $service->sum(0, 0);
```

Comment: @Sherif Bit quick on the draw there, how about a comment explaining

Comment: Thank you for the swift response, this works as intended!

Comment: Merci Mon ami @Funk

Comment: Can't upvote yet Riggs (ran out). I fixed a typo and obviously *not* my downvote ;-) No idea why you got that. Edit: welcome.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner tell me, would this work if, let's say, there were thousand random calls to sum() on an array of million elements? how would the stress testing go?

Comment: @IntenseFlegdev Probably, can't see why not. If the processor is fast enough and the db is properly indexed if it is db related, couldn't see why a million elements would make things bog. Run a benchmark and you'll see. If it takes too many resources, then you'd have to put a trace on it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly A typo is hardly worthy of an answer, in my opinion as it's unlikely to serve the greater community (way too specific of a problem to be generally applicable and way to narrow of a question title to be easily searchable). However, if you are going to give an answer it should be more than just here's how you fix the typo. I'd prefer an explanation of local variables versus instance variables at least. Anyway, I removed my down vote just FYI.